# Policy Entitlement XACML in WSO2 Identity Server with WSO2 API Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I am having an requirement where I have integrated WSO2 Identity server(5.3) internal LDAP with WSO2 API Manager(2.1).

I have done the changes by un-commenting the LDAP configuration in wso2-api-2.1\repository\conf\user-mgt.xml by uncommenting the below code.

```
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager">
and commented the below.
<UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.jdbc.JDBCUserStoreManager">
```

I followed all steps mentioned in the WSO2 documentation for Role-based Access control using XACML as below.
https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML

I created a role 'schooladmin' and a user 'testuser'. I assigned the role'schooladmin' to 'testuser' in Identity server along with all Permissions granted.

I am able to test the PDP in WSO2 Identity store and it works fine.

Issues:

1. As Identity Server and API Manager are connected via LDAP, I can't see PDP developed in Identity Server available in API Manager. Is this correct behaviour?
2. I created and deployed an REST API basis a business service and added Entitlement during configuration as mentioned in the WSO2 documentation.

   ```
               <sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"  name="newEntitlementMediator"> 
                   <entitlementService xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" remoteServiceUrl="https://localhost:9443/services" remoteServiceUserName="admin" remoteServicePassword="admin" 
                   callbackClass="org.wso2.sample.handlers.entitlement.APIEntitlementCallbackHandler"/>
                   </sequence>
   ```

When I am trying to newly developed REST API in Postman, I am always getting the below error.

```
<am:fault xmlns:am="http://wso2.org/apimanager">
    <am:code>0</am:code>
    <am:type>Status report</am:type>
    <am:message>Runtime Error</am:message>
    <am:description>User is not authorized to perform the action</am:description>
</am:fault>
```

For testing, I am creating new token with correct user 'testuser' using the below service provided - https://localhost:8244/token

Please suggest if there is any limitation or I missed any configuration.

I am adding the Policy created in WSO2 IS server for entitlement.
Please review.

```
<Policy xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:core:schema:wd-17" PolicyId="iib_policy_entitlement" RuleCombiningAlgId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:rule-combining-algorithm:deny-unless-permit" Version="1.0">
   <Target/>
   <Rule Effect="Permit" RuleId="iib_test_rule">
      <Target>
         <AnyOf>
            <AllOf>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">/login/v1</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:resource:resource-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:resource" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
               <Match MatchId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-equal">
                  <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">POST</AttributeValue>
                  <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:action:action-id" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:3.0:attribute-category:action" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
               </Match>
            </AllOf>
         </AnyOf>
      </Target>
      <Condition>
         <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-at-least-one-member-of">
            <Apply FunctionId="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:function:string-bag">
               <AttributeValue DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string">iib_role</AttributeValue>
            </Apply>
            <AttributeDesignator AttributeId="http://wso2.org/claims/role" Category="urn:oasis:names:tc:xacml:1.0:subject-category:access-subject" DataType="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#string" MustBePresent="true"/>
         </Apply>
      </Condition>
   </Rule>
</Policy>
```

Thanks,
Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

Answers for question 1: Yes, LDAP is used only as the user store. Meta data is stored in a separate DB. If you need to share the meta data as well then you have share the meta data DBs as well. Please change /repository/conf/datasourses/master-datasourses.xml for that.

Answer for question 2: Cannot answer this question directly but I can give you few points to check.

- Check whether you can see that the created user and role from the API manager side.
- Do you want IS to act as the key manger for the APIM ? If so please check this documentation. [IS as a Key Manager](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Configuring+WSO2+Identity+Server+as+a+Key+Manager)

Comment: I am able to see users and roles created in IS getting reflected in APIM. The problem stated is when I attach Entitlement mentioned above to connect to PDP created in IS for Role-based authentication using XACML. It fails and shows the error as User is not authorized to perform the action. I am not sure what is the missing configuration here. I followed all steps mentioned in the reference documentation. https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM210/Enabling+Role-Based+Access+Control+Using+XACML